# Applying Entity Framework Core's Database Update to PostgreSQL server on a docker container with SSH

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssh, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm a bit new to SQL and Docker. I've recently created a container for PostgreSQL on my Linux server that can be accessed by SSH. I am trying to manage it using the Entity Framework on .NET Core 2.2.

I'm trying to go by [Npgsql's official documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html), but there isn't any provision for connection via SSH. The example they've provided for the connection string is:

```
optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=my_host;Database=my_db;Username=my_user;Password=my_pw")
```

Where:

- **my_host** is set to the *docker container's* IP address.
- **my_db** is the database name
- **my_user** is the username on PostgreSQL
- **my_pw** is the database password

I am also using this [First EF Core Console Application](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx) as a tutorial. When I am attempting on the dotnet CLI:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

It keeps timing out, obviously because it can't connect to the server via SSH.

I've done my fair share of Googling with no luck. Can any of you please advise?

**Edit** FYI:

- I am using a Windows 10 computer as a client
- I am using Ubuntu Linux and connecting via OpenSSH
- The Linux server has a Docker Container w/ PostgreSQL
- I have successfully connected from my Windows 10 client using DBeaver

Answer (score -1):

In principle, connecting to PostgreSQL isn't done over SSH - it's done directly via port 5432. You typically need to configure your container to expose that port (check the docker networking docs).

It is possible to use SSH tunneling to connect to PG (or any other service), but that's a pretty specialized mechanism to bypass firewalls and the like. You likely just need to expose port 5432 from your container.

Comment: I am able to connect to this database with DBeaver from the same client (a Windows 10 system) using SSH tunneling to an Open SSH server (on Ubuntu Linux) that has a Docker container for PostgreSQL. I've had to provide DBeaver with my server's IP and SSH port of the Linux Server as well as the Docker container's IP and port 5432. I can't seem to replicate that on the Entity Framework. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I don't know DBeaver. Npgsql simply needs a host and port from you, connects to it and expects to find a PostgreSQL instance on the other side. If you've set up SSH tunneling to make that happen, Npgsql doesn't know or care - it's transparent as far as it's concerned.